# SoftLayer REST API Cancellation Request

Tags: api, virtual-machine, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to cancel a `SoftLayer` device on a certain date in the future and found the following `SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request::createObject`.

What would the `request url` look like and what would the `POST parameters` look like if I was using json?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that worked for me is the following:

1. https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[deviceID]/getBillingItem.json
2. https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/[BillingItemID]/cancelServiceOnAnniversaryDate.json

Both are `Get` Requests.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Rest example can help you:

[Cancel Service - rest](https://softlayer.github.io/rest/cancel_service/)

To get billing item, please see:

[SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getBillingItem](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getBillingItem)

Also, this is a Python example:

```
"""
Cancel a Virtual Guest.
It cancels the resource for a billing Item. The billing item will be cancelled
immediately and reclaim of the resource will begin shortly.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getObject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelService

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer.API
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
API_USERNAME = 'set me'

# Generate one at https://control.softlayer.com/account/users
API_KEY = 'set me'

virtualGuestId = 9923645

client = SoftLayer.Client(
    username=API_USERNAME,
    api_key=API_KEY,
)

try:
    # Getting the billing item id
    mask = 'mask.billingItem.id'
    cci = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'].getObject(mask=mask, id=virtualGuestId)
    billingItemId = cci['billingItem']['id']

    try:
        # Canceling the Virtual Guest
        result = client['Billing_Item'].cancelService(id=billingItemId)
        pp(result)
    except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        pp('Unable to cancel the VSI faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
            % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        pp('Unable to get the billing item id from VSI faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
            % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Also there are a lot examples in other clients can help you:

[Cancel Service - rest](https://softlayer.github.io/rest/cancel_service/)

[Cancel service - Python](https://softlayer.github.io/python/cancel_service/)

[cancel service - php](https://softlayer.github.io/php/cancelservice/)

[cancel service-perl](https://softlayer.github.io/perl/cancelitem/)

**References**

[SoftLayer_Billing_Item::cancelService](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelService)

[SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getBillingItem](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getBillingItem)

[SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getObject)

Comment: This is not what I was trying to do. I want to cancel a virtual device some time in the future, which means I would need to attach some sort of date/time object to the request. Does something like that exist for SoftLayer?

Answer (score 0):

This may be what are you looking for:

```
Post URL: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/createObject.json

Payload: 

{
    "parameters": [
        {
            "complexType": "SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request",
            "accountId": 321752,
            "notes": "No notes provided",
            "items": [
                {
                    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request_Item",
                    "billingItemId": 25849466,
                    "scheduledCancellationDate": "5/15/2006"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thank you, that looks like what I need :)

Comment: This and a little different version of the Request don't work for me.

Comment: Failed to cancel billing items. Failed to determine the ticket group for reclaiming "Computing Instance"

Comment: are you sure that the billingItem id is the correct?

Comment: I'm using the following to get it: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[id]/getBillingItem.json

Comment: it looks like an issue, because according this method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/validateBillingItemForCancellation the billing item id of VSI is valid for cancellation, I suggest you to submit a ticket about this in softlayer´s portal.